# Vlookup in a User form not working, Cant find string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

New to VBA, and using it in Excel.

I have a User form, and I am trying to use a lookup to fill TextBox4 from the value that is entered in ComboBox3. I have the following code which compiles, however it is producing the msgbox to say that the string cant be found...

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

    Dim strFind As String
    Dim rFound As Range
    ws = "Year-to-Date Summary"

    If ComboBox3.ListIndex > -1 Then
        strFind = ComboBox3
        On Error Resume Next
        With ws.Column(2, 3)
            Set rFound = .Find(What:="strFind", After:=.Cells(39, 49), _
            LookIn:=.Cells(39, 49), LookAt _
            :=.Cells(39, 49), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ 
            MatchCase:= False)
        End With

        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox strFind & " cannot be found"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            TextBox4 = rFound(1, 2)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

I also tried Vlookup, however this sprung error messages...

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

TextBox4.Text = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(ComboBox3.Text), _
Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary").Range("C39:C49" & LastRow), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the string you are searching is really avaialble? Why don't you use VLookup to do the search?

Comment: i tried vlookup however it wouldnt complile. i am a relative novice in VBA. i will edit question to show vlookup code as well. maybe you could check it?

Comment: when i use the Vlookup code, it errors that 'unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class'

Comment: As David mention, it's advisable to have `Option Explicit` as it encourages you to declare all your variables that you intend to use for a code. If it's not declared well, editor will triger you an error without further headaches. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

TextBox4.Text = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox3.Text, Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary").Range("$B$39:$C$49"), 2, False)

TextBox3.Text = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.TextBox4.Text, Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary").Range("$C$39:$D$49"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

This worked for me, to do two textboxes from the combobox

Answer (score 1):

1. ws is a variant. You do not assign worksheets like this. You have to use `Set`
2. strFind is within quotes so it will be considered as a string

See this example (**UNTESTED**)

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    If ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim strFind As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary")

    strFind = ComboBox3.Value

    Set rFound = ws.Columns(3).Find(What:=strFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        TextBox4 = rFound.Offset(,1)
    Else
        MsgBox strFind & " cannot be found"
    End If
End Sub
```

If your range is fixed then change `ws.Columns(3)` to `ws.Range("C39:C49")`  in the above code.

If you would like to use the worksheet function then you this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

**Note**: I have not used error trapping in the below code. i am sure you can take care of that.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    If ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub

    TextBox4.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                    Val(ComboBox3.Value), _
                    Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary").Range("C39:D49"), _
                    2, _
                    False _
                    )
End Sub
```

Note how we used `C39:C49 / Columns(3) + Offset` in the first example and how we used `C49:D49` in the 2nd Example

**EDIT**: I forgot to comment on `On Error Resume Next` Never use it until and unless required. It is like telling the code to "shut up!" if it finds an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ws is obviously a string, which does not have a .column property.
Replace line `ws = "Year-to-Date Summary"` by
`set ws = worksheets("Year-to-Date Summary")` and see if that helps.

Do you make sure that every module has an "`Option Explicit`" and that your app compiles successfully ? You would have spotted that error I think.

Comment: I missed to update the WS in the code snippet here. Thanks for pointing it out though. Most obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

```
Dim strFind As String
Dim rFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Year-to-Date Summary")

If ComboBox3.ListIndex > -1 Then
    strFind = ComboBox3.text
    On Error Resume Next
```

'editted removing the whole vlookup part...
'added for loop to search the text within the range

```
    Set rSearch = ws.Range("B:C")            
            For Each rFound In rSearch
                If rFound.Value = strFind Then
                 TextBox4.Text = rFound.value
                else
                 MsgBox strFind & " cannot be found"
                 Exit Sub
                End If                
            Next rFound        
End Sub
```

Comment: still comes up with the msgbox. just to check, if the linked data is in cells B39:C49 (ColB is where the ComboBox roots from, ColC is where the name of the linked person is located) the code is correct?

Comment: sorry I missed out to update your code block's WS. now you have many ways to do this look up, use Find, VLookUp or a For loop.